# Why is the distribution of the clustering coefficient of a random network independent of degree?

Tags: graphs

I was reading about clustering coefficient distribution, and it seems that it is independent of node degree for the case of random networks, or even scale-free networks. I'm wondering why this is the case conceptually.

I do understand that the degree distribution in the case of a random network shows a Poisson behavior, but don't understand why the clustering coefficient shows no change with degree.

Edit: my claim about clustering coefficient distribution with respect to random graphs comes from [box 2 in this article](https://www.nature.com/articles/nrg1272):

[image]

Comment: Could you give reference to the claim "distribution of clustering coefficient among random graphs is independent of the node degree [parameter]"? To be honest, the topic is new to me and I just want to learn. However, I think it is useful to be extra clear about which claims are you requesting their proofs to be explained. What's unclear to me in particular is how do you parameterized random graph generation by degree. Are you perhaps considering the set of graphs which all nodes have exactly a specific degree?

Comment: Hi @ApiwatChantawibul, I am adding a reference to my post, hopefully it will help